# SPARQL consider additional triples in a query

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

So, I need to run SPARQL query over a semantic database but some of the triples are not going to be in the database but are going to be provided by webservices (and not as a SPARQL endpoint). I would want to be able to run a SELECT query that take into consideration those additional triples but without having to insert them in the database, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Maybe you somehow could make a view over your graph store that contains the extra triples?

Comment: that's not part of the SPARQL spec, so "no". Indeed, some triple stores do support extension like virtual graphs, but an arbitrary webservice for sure not. You would have to implement it by yourself I guess. I mean, that would need the triple store to fetch some data on demand on some unknown language which would have to return RDF in order to be able to combine it with the locally loaded RDF data. For example, joins have to be done in-memory at some point.

Answer (score 1):

This is not part of the SPARQL spec, so "no" is the general answer.

That said, Virtuoso (possibly among others) lets you include an external RDF source (a/k/a webservice) as part of the `FROM` (among other methods), to be dereferenced during SPARQL query processing.

Such webservice need not be a SPARQL endpoint, but best performance will result if it provides RDF (though serialization may vary).

The [Virtuoso Sponger](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSponger) can also be invoked on the fly to derive RDF from many document formats (with an obvious performance hit). To pursue, please raise this to the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com).